# Proving $6^n - 1$ is always divisible by 5 by direct proof, not induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to solve the problem:

$5|(6^n-1)$ with $n > 0$

I'm thinking about $6^n$ always ends with 6 as the last digit and subtract $1$ we have $5$ as the last digit of $(6^n - 1)$. 
A number with $5$ as the last digit is always divisible by $5$.

However, I don't know how to use direct proof to prove that.

Edit: I don't want to use induction proof.

Comment: What is "direct proof" for you and in this context? And your idea looks pretty good: show that any power of $\;6\;$ ends in 6...and continue as you wrote there. This is pretty straightforward....or direct. :)

Comment: This question is attracting so many excellent non-inductive proofs that I recommend it be left open.

Comment: @DonAntonio With direct proof, I mean write (6^n - 1) equal something as 5k.

Comment: Every rigorous proof will use induction in one form or another.

Answer (score 9):

$6^n-1=(6-1)(6^{n-1}+6^{n-2}+\cdots +1)$ and first part is divisible by 5

Comment: Note that this *does* use induction if you write the proof rigorously.

Answer (score 3):

You have $$6^n-1\equiv 1^n-1=1-1=0\mod 5$$ for every non-negative integer $n$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Expand $6^n=(5+1)^n$ with the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If $m$ and $n$ both have $6$ in their unit position, then $mn$ does as well (since $6 \cdot 6 = 36$, leaving a $6$ in the unit position of the product).

Next, wave your hands a bit (or do it formally by induction) to observe that $6 \cdot 6 \cdots 6$ will have a $6$ in its unit position (since you start with $6 \cdot 6 = 36$ and keep multiplying by $6$).

Your argument then follows: Since $6^n$ has a $6$ in its unit position, then $6^n - 1$ has a $5$ in its unit position, and is therefore (by well-known divisibility rules) divisible by $5$.

Answer (score 0):

For fun:

1)$\sum :=          6^{n-1}+6^{n-2}+......6^0$;

2) $6\sum=6^n + 6^{n-1}+.......6^1$;

Subtract: $2)-1)$:

$5\sum= 6^n -6^0=6^n-1$.

Hence?